# Please enter a valid region error for regions with special characters

Tags: import, importexport, customer-address, country-regions, regions

I'm trying to import customer addresses. If the region has a name with accents, Magento v2.3.6 won't recognize it.

Example:

- Country code 'RO', region 'Timiș' - doesn't work
- Country code 'RO', region 'Timis' - doesn't work
- Country code 'RO', region 'Olt' - works
- Country code 'RO', region 'Brașov' - doesn't work

In the DB, regions do have accents.

I can swear it used to work on a previous Magento version, but I'm not 100% sure.

[Related question (did not help)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311727/v2-3-4-customer-import-please-enter-a-valid-region)

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, `ș` (U+0219, in my import file, which also comes off my keyboard) was different from `ş` (U+015F, in the DB).

I just changed all DB regions to contain the more common version of the character.

Also be careful about `ț`'s